# "fastboot -l devices" returns nothing

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, fastboot

I'm a newbie trying to learn about what alternative firmware I could use to upgrade my Nexus Galaxy from Android 4.2.1.

After connecting the phone to my Windows PC with a USB cable, I followed [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE7vPTYfUtE) on YouTube to start the Nexus in Fastboot mode, clicked on the right button to proceed, and once Android was up and running, ran this from Windows...

`[c:\Android-adb]fastboot.exe -l devices`

... which returns nothing.

Any idea why, and what to do?

FWIW, the phone is also running an ADB server since it's used by the [MyPhoneExplorer application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyPhoneExplorer) to sync Outlook with Android.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

The computer already had the Samsung driver since I'm using MPE to sync Outlook with the Android phone.

1. Next, on a new computer, downloaded and installed [Galaxy Nexus Toolkit 11.1.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392310), and rebooted as prompted by Windows7. With phone plugged in, Windows7 detected the phone allright.
2. Rebooted, left in Fastboot mode: fastboot-toolkit.exe says nothing, and Windows7 complains with "Device driver software was not successfully installed".
3. Couldn't uninstall GNToolkit, as it's not listed in Programs. Downloaded and unzipped Android SDK in c:\Android-adb\, edited PATH, rebooted, and with phone still plugged in and waiting in Fastboot mode, ran "fastboot.exe -l devices": Still nothing.

---

Edit:

1. On new computer, downloaded and installed [Galaxy Nexus Toolkit 11.1.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392310), rebooted as prompted by Windows7
2. Without rebooting, plugged phone: Windows7 complained with "Device driver software was not successfully installed". Followed [this howto](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1830108) to manually update driver.
3. Rebooted with phone still plugged: Phone detected OK.
4. Rebooted phone in Fastboot mode, and rebooted Windows7: "Device driver software was not successfully installed" followed by "Google Galaxy Nexus BootLoader Interface: Failed".
5. Device Manager shows faulty "Android Device > Google Galaxy Nexus BootLoader Interface", but telling Windows to look for driver in C:\GoogleNexusToolkit ends with "The best driver software for your device is already installed."

What could be the problem?

Thank  you.

Comment: Could you explain a little further what you mean by "clicked on the right button to proceed, and once Android was up and running"? Booting Android leaves fastboot mode, so you shouldn't expect it to be visible to the `fastboot` tool then.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I thought I should proceed with booting Android. Still, while in Fastboot mode, "fastboot -l devices" returns nothing. I notice that XP displays the familiar "Welcome to the Found New Hardware Wizard" message. Is there something I need to install?

Comment: How about drivers? :) On Windows, everything needs drivers. Never heard of the famous error message: "Mouse driver not found. Spank the cat?" :D

Comment: @Gulbahar I don't know, I've never used fastboot on Windows. You should add that information to your question so that other visitors will see it.

Comment: You might want to post your PATH, as you may not have edited it correctly.  You can also try opening a command window and dragging the fastboot executable to it from Windows Explorer, which should expand out the full path to it, and then running it with  "-l devices".

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is with faulty drivers, not with the PATH. See edited question for more information.